# Making Network Requests through React Native

Tags: django, reactjs, react-native

I have just started learning React Native. Built my Component and am trying to use an authenticate function written in a separate file to authenticate.

My Authenticate file looks like

```
var constants = require("../constants")

module.exports = function(usr,pwd){

    var trailing_url = '/api/token/';

    var url = constants.DOMAIN + trailing_url;
    console.log("url");

    return fetch(url, {
        method: "POST", 
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: usr, 
          password: pwd, 
        })
      }).then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(json){
        return json;
    });
}
```

I am experiencing this error once i go to fetch. I am unable to make network requests to my backend in django which is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/

I am getting the following error. Couldn't copy paste that here for some reason.
[image: Error Image]

Another question I had is how to debug the code? I tried the Chrome debugger.
But its showing
**Status: Waiting, press Ctrl R in simulator to reload and connect.**
Tried refreshing the Simulator but didn't work.

Comment: You are running in emulator, So 127.0.0.1(localhost) is not the server address. You have to find the ip address of the machine. Emulator IP can be find with `adb devices` in console.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ashutosh for pointing that out. I didn't notice that since the emulator is a different machine, it wouldn't actually recognize localhost or 127.0.0.1

The problem was i was using the local machine's Loopback IP Address when requesting for data.